# strange tick in pgfplot showing on top of figure

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to create a very simple plot, and I almost got the desired result, except for a very strange x-tick on top of the figure.
This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
      unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
      xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
      ymin=0,ymax=1.5,
      axis line style={draw=none},
      xtick={0},
      xticklabels={$i$},
      ymajorticks=false,
  ]

  \draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);   

  \addplot [] coordinates {
      (-1.5, 1.5) (0, 0) };
  \addplot [] coordinates {
      (0,0) (1.5,1.5)};

\end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I could use `xmajorticks=false,` but then this removes not only the tick at the top, but also the one at the bottom plus the label (which I need).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing strange about that tick, the default behaviour is to have ticks on both sides, so top and bottom for x-axis, left and right for y-axis.

Add

```
xtick pos=bottom
```

before the `axis line style` setting to get ticks only at the bottom.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
      unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
      xmin=-1.5,xmax=1.5,
      ymin=0,ymax=1.5,
      xtick pos=bottom, % <-- add before axis line style
      axis line style={draw=none},
      xtick={0},
      xticklabels={$i$},
      ymajorticks=false,
  ]

  \draw[ultra thin] (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin},0) -- (axis cs:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},0);   

  \addplot [] coordinates {
      (-1.5, 1.5) (0, 0) };
  \addplot [] coordinates {
      (0,0) (1.5,1.5)};

\end{axis}    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```